# Modification of expand.grid function in R

Tags: r

I need to create a matrix of all possible combinations.

```
L<-12 
vec <- c(0:21)
lst <- lapply(numeric(L), function(x) vec)
Mat1<-as.matrix(expand.grid(lst))
```

Result would be very big matrix and my computer cannot calculate it. 
Actually, I need only combinations where value in the first column is greater then value in the second one, in the second column is greater then in the third one and so on. Can I modify expand.grid function somehow to drop unnecessary combinations?

Comment: Is the vector 0:21 really the numbers you are interested in, or just a sample vector created to give us something to work on? If it is, then the combinatorically-based answers below will work, otherwise they wont...

Comment: @Spacedman IINM the more robust versions would deal with (1) duplicates and (2) missing values. I think OP's main issue was creating a massive 22^12-size (380 petabit) output (not possible) & subsetting to what he needs -- both answers below solve that, and IINM can be fixed with a few further subsets to accommodate these generalizations

Comment: what if the constituent vectors aren't even sorted? this is why I like to ask for clarification before posting an answer in cases like this! I suppose OP does say "combinations" which might mean combn(0:21,11) (or similar)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this quite easily using `combinations` from the `gtools` package:

```r
result <- gtools::combinations(length(vec), L, vec)[, L:1]
```

The function itself gives the columns in increasing order, so the subset is there just to get the order right.

It is a large matrix, so it takes some time, but only around 5 seconds on my slow work PC:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(combinations(22, 12, 21:0)[,12:1], times = 5)
Unit: seconds
                              expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
combinations(22, 12, 21:0)[, 12:1] 4.965595 5.211964 5.261557 5.249413 5.341981 5.538831     5
```

We can see that the first 5 rows give the correct format:

```r
result[1:5,]
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
#> [1,]   11   10    9    8    7    6    5    4    3     2     1     0
#> [2,]   12   10    9    8    7    6    5    4    3     2     1     0
#> [3,]   13   10    9    8    7    6    5    4    3     2     1     0
#> [4,]   14   10    9    8    7    6    5    4    3     2     1     0
#> [5,]   15   10    9    8    7    6    5    4    3     2     1     0
```

And that we have the correct dimensions:

```
dim(result)
#> [1] 646646     12
```

Answer (score 5):

As @AllanCameron identified, what you're after is equivalent to taking all combinations of `vec` of size 12 -- you can also use the built-in function `combn` for that:

```
do.call(rbind, combn(vec, L, simplify = FALSE))
```

It may be faster to use `data.table` to manipulate the output of `combn` into the desired format:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(transpose(combn(vec, L, simplify=FALSE))
```

Comment: I guess `rev(vec)` should be used here, since OP "need only combinations where value in the first column is greater then value in the second one, in the second column is greater then in the third one and so on."

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding yes indeed! Alternatively, with the `data.table` solution assigned as `x` we can do `setcolorder(x, ncol(x):1)`